# Online file conversion API (DOC, PPT etc. to JPG)

Tags: web-services

I am looking for an online file conversion site which converts DOCX, DOC, PPT, PDF etc. to JPG files using an API (RESTful etc.).

I do not mind paying for the service but am unable to find an such service online.

Comment: +1 interested in this too! What'd you end up doing?

Comment: Groupdocs.Convertion Cloud(https://products.groupdocs.cloud/conversion) is another Document and Image Conversion REST API Solution. It converts 50+ file formats from one format to other on any platform. Its free package plan provides 50 credits per month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One that might work for you is convertapi (http://www.convertapi.com/).

I recently used this to enable the following conversions for an app :

- doc/docx --> PDF
- ppt --> jpg
- doc/docx --> jpg

They have a very simple REST api that's easy to implement : (http://www.convertapi.com/api/word-pdf-api)

Answer (score 1):

You probably should also have a look at the [CloudConvert API](https://cloudconvert.com/api), which,  as far as I know, supports your mentioned formats.

Answer (score -1):

Convertapi doesn't do ppt --> jpg at the moment.

Comment: It do http://www.convertapi.com/powerpoint-pdf-api There is OutputFormat there you cna set jpg as output format.